# How to pass the exact search result into a new URL

Tags: forms

So I'm using a form in a specific page and I want to pass the exact search query to another url after submission

**Example**: I search for vehicles and I need the result to be `domain.com/search/vehicles`

So this is what I have so far:

```
<form id="" action="domain.com/" method="get">
<input type="text" name="search" />
<input type="submit" value="click here" />
</form>
```

The actual url result here is: `domain.com/?search=vehicles`

I can't figure out how to make it work

Comment: Forms pass inputs as parameters when you submit them. You can use javascript to change pages instead.`document.location.href = newUrl;`

Answer (score 0):

HTML forms will send the inputs in it as GET or POST (or DELETE or PUT also, I think) parameters. So they will send it as `url?parameter1=xxx`, they won't incorporate them in the url as you want like this `url/parameter1/xxx/`. I think to do it as you want is easier with jQuery (or plain javascript).

You can do this with jQuery, for example:

```
$("#form-id").submit(function() {
    event.preventDefault(); // stops form from executing normal behavior
    var newUrl = // get new url parameters and mount it;
    document.location.href = newUrl; // sends to new location
    /* Do Something */
    return false;
});
```

`document.location.href` in javascript will redirect you to a new page.